# How can I use sensory details to convey to the reader that something is being digested in acid?

Tags: chemistry, biochemistry, microorganisms

I have a scene where a slime monster engulfs a person and begins digesting them by secreting acid. This scene is being viewed from the perspective of another person standing some distance away. I haven't really decided what the precise acid being secreted in this scene is, I'm pretty sure I'll have to fudge the details a little for the sake of the story because few real acids are as aggressive as [acids as frequently portrayed in fiction](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodAcid), though I'd like to try and keep the acid something a real organism could produce (the slime monster is basically a giant colony of killer extremophilic archaea). A [piranha solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution) might be the closest one could get in terms of real chemistry.

I need some way to show to the audience that acid is being secreted through sensory details, rather than just bluntly stating it through exposition, and that the slime monster isn't just grabbing the person with pseudopods but actively starting to digest them as it grabs them *during* the scene (e.g., a sentence of detail). Because of the nature of the story I can't show anything extremely graphic to demonstrate this, like flesh melting off or the stereotypical "[acid leaves nothing but bones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q84EBlzLoOA)".

I had considered a line saying the observer sees the person steaming where the pseudopods touched them and smelled "the distinct tang of acid" as they watched the scene. However, I'm also aware that most acids are odorless, colorless liquids and so the line didn't seem to work. I've seen conflicting statements as to whether the primary acid used in digestion in many organisms, hydrochloric acid, produces any sort of odor. Sulfuric acid also doesn't have an odor but it may be associated with hydrogen sulfide, which does. I have been unable to find if piranha solutions have a smell. **How can I signify to the audience that acid is being used in this scene via showing, not telling, given that acids generally don't have a recognizable smell or appearance**?

Comment: Most life forms (especially single-cell ones) don't secrete acid as the primary means of digestion. They frequently use enzymes that break down the materials into useful components. Acid in those concentrations creates a toxic environment for the organism. The stomach can get away with it by creating an acid-resistant layer to contain the hazardous materials.

Comment: While some of the acids may be odorless when pure, the situation changes when they begin attacking something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not asking how to develop and consistently use the rules and systems of the OP's fictional world. It's asking for advice about how to write. That kind of question is the reason [writing.se] exists. I recommend the question be migrated there.

Comment: piranha solution smells like well... hydrogen peroxide (it is one of the ingredients). The "distinct tang of acid" usually comes from the fact that if you don't know that the environment is full of acid, some acids that release a bit of vapor or get aerosolized will irritate your airways and eyes

Comment: I agree with JBH : While we could talk about acid sensory details from a worldbuilding perspective, however here it's more about how to convey the feeling than how you'd feel if thrown against it. The difference might be subtle, but artists have since long proved me that they're entirely different things :p.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact It would just end up getting closed there because it's not about the process of writing, it concerns the scientific principles of how acid smells or looks (hydrochloric acid will always smell like hydrochloric acid), and thus is more about how the writing interacts with science and the world and thus will be said to go back here. "How the story is affected by setting and science" is usually considered a Worldbuilding SE question.

Comment: @user2352714 That shouldn't be true. Trying to explain how to express in writing any sensory experience ***is*** the process of writing. But, it's still not within the scope of WB.SE.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact But in this case it's not asking something subjective, it's asking something concrete: all chemicals have distinct properties that are always present (appearance, odor, melting and boiling point), and no amount of subjective flourishes from the author will change that. Stripping the story elements, the question can be rephrased as "how can you tell an acid is present when acids are usually colorless and odorless".

Answer (score 1):

**Acid jellifies.**

[image: jelly chicken leg]

[Flesh-Eating Hydrofluoric Acid - Periodic Table of Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oipksRhISfM)

Periodic videos has many videos of putting meat in acid.  It is less than spectacular.  This jellification seems to be a common principle - I suspect it is denatured proteins making a dark jellied mass that slumps away from underlying tissue.

On this same video an interesting thing specific to hydrofluoric acid is that it bleached the chicken - other acids left some edible-looking reddish myoglobin but hydrofluoric turned the whole thing a horrid greenish gray.

Professor Poliakoff in this video recounts that he heard that hydrofluoric acid kills the nerves first and so if you get it in a leaky glove it is painless even as it works.  That would be nice for your dissolving character and kind of unexpected.

You could watch this and related acid videos and consider how you would describe the appearance of the variously treated meats in your own distinctive style.  Then use those descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

> This scene is being viewed from the perspective of another person standing some distance away

The sounds made by the victim are likely to be pretty horrific... acids burn the skin, and with the exception of some oddballs like hydrofluoric acid (which your beasties are very unlikely to secrete, due to the rarity of fluorine-bearing compounds in the environment) they'll certainly trigger pain-sensitive nerves. They'll panic and flail ineffectually and eventually go quiet as it smothers them.

It might not be visibly different from, say, someone being smothered by a load of boiling hot slime, so you'll need to add smells in too. Sulphuric acid may be odorless and has a pretty low vapour pressure, but fine aerosols can be generated (especially by, say, a mobile acid monster slooshing around and wrestling with a human) and they can irritate the nose and eyes. Many acids will have similar effects. People have described these vapors as "acrid" or "suffocating", even if they don't have a particular smell as such.

There may be some visible effects of the acid reactions, depending on quite how strong the chemicals are. Concentrated acids can produce visible fumes like little clouds of steam or smoke. If the victim had anything reactive on their person, metals especially, these might visibly fizz and fume. Concentrated acids on flesh seem likely to produce strong but strange odors... not like cooked or spoiled meat but not entirely dissimilar. Maybe like the aftermath of a bad culinary experiment. The observer would probably find it unfamiliar at first, but distinctive enough that they'd recognise it again.

So the take home, I guess, is not to have the observer standing too far away. They need to be close enough to see small-scale fizzing and fuming, and they need to be able to smell the byproducts of digestion. They might be able to see the corpse afterwards and it will look like the skin has been scalded and damaged all over and clothing may be holed or pitted.

> Because of the nature of the story I can't show anything extremely graphic to demonstrate this, like flesh melting off or the stereotypical "acid leaves nothing but bones".

It probably won't leave bones, to be honest. Breaking down the mineralised bits of tissue is probably easier than breaking down the meaty bits. If you want to leave the bones behind, you'd need to use a very strong alkali instead.

It'll take a long time to break the body down into soup... according to [some research](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/27441/how-hard-it-dissolve-body) it'll take a couple of days, with enough acid.

> I'd like to try and keep the acid something a real organism could produce (the slime monster is basically a giant colony of killer extremophilic archaea).

As I've just hinted, acids aren't great at digesting things. Your own stomach acid isn't there to dissolve your food, but to provide a suitable chemical environment to help denature some chemicals and facilitate the work of other digestive enzymes.

Flesh eating toxins won't have the same graphic effects as concentrated acids, in terms of fizzing and smoking, but they will do a bang-up job of turning meat into useful nutrients. Being smothered by a slime monster that then turns you to soup over the next 12 hours might not be the scene you were really after, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Use of Victim’s Sensory Description**

Increasingly more macabre: sensation, pain, biting, caustic, up to “Gaah, my hand is gone!”

“Vickie, the victim, pulled away from the pseudopod, and it resisted. And as she resisted more, it burned more. Then the pain stopped as Vickie managed to pull loose.

Reality dawned on Vickie when she locked eyes with Tom. Tom was horrified to see the pseudopods has dissolved through Vickie’s arms…”

**Use of Narrator’s Reaction**
In this case, Tom can be used to sanitize the graphic horror:
Tom could not stand the sight any longer, and looked away [covered ears | held nose]. “God, the blood [sound | smell],” Tom thought. When he peaked through his eyes, the huddling biomass was no longer recognizable as his friend…”

**Sound**

“The tentantacle splorted around his wrist…”
“Oh god!” The ooze splatted onto his exposed flesh, sizzling as it burned into him..,”

**Metaphor**

“The tentacles splorted around his wrist…
…cutting through like a hot knife into butter.”